# How to disable 3.1 "Admin Bar" via script for the admin user?

Tags: theme-development, php, customization, admin-bar

Every time I create a new site under 3.1, my first trip is to the Users > Admin User profile page to uncheck the "admin bar" checkbox.

I'd like to place a script in my theme's functions.php to do this automatically.

Anyone know what that would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a function inside your theme's functions file to selectively disable it for specific users.

```
function disable_bar_for_user( $ids ) {

    if( !is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    global $current_user;

    if( is_numeric( $ids ) )
        $ids = (array) $ids;

    if( !in_array( $current_user->data->ID, $ids ) )
        return;

    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false', 9 );
}
```

Then call it for the user or users you want to disable the bar for..

**Single user:**

```
disable_bar_for_user(1);
```

**Multiple users:**

```
disable_bar_for_user(array(1,2,3));
```

If you want to just turn it off altogether, then the following should do it(instead of the function).

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false', 9 );
```

Hope that helps.. :)

Answer (score 3):

For functions.php:

```
// Disable the Admin Bar for All

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can activate such a plugin sitewide - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-admin-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `show_admin_bar` filter to false in your functions.php.